# Not able to bind click event in jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery

I have a button which by default is disabled. After I select an item from jQuery UI Autocomplete, I want to enable the button.

I'm testing if this works by using an alert on the button:

```
jQuery('#btn').live('click', function() { alert('test'); });
```

First I tried this solution:

```
jQuery('.autocomplete_brand').live('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui){
      jQuery('#btn').removeClass('inactive').attr('disabled',''); 
});
```

This enables the button, but then I was reminded that this will not work, because `.live` only works on `click` events. So I changed the code to this:

```
jQuery('.ui-menu-item a').live('click', function() {
  jQuery('#btn').removeClass('inactive').attr('disabled','');
});
```

This almost works. The `disable` attribute is blanked out, but the alert will still not trigger when I click the button.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using? The following:

> This enables the button, but then I
>   was reminded that this will not work,
>   because .live only works on click
>   events.

Is not true for >= 1.44 (and may be true for versions even before that. **Edit:** I'm almost positive this will work with >= 1.3, when `live` was added.).

You can do exactly what you were trying to do with the `autocompleteselect` event:

```
jQuery('.autocomplete_brand').live('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui){
      jQuery('#btn').removeClass('inactive').attr('disabled',''); 
});
```

If you're using jQuery >= 1.6, however, you'll want to use `prop`:

```
jQuery("#btn").removeClass("inactive").prop("disabled", false);
```

Here it is working with jQuery 1.6:

http://jsfiddle.net/wGH32/

Comment: I'm using 1.8x. I think the `prop` was the issue. Using that, it now works. Thanks! :)